# Firebase query with subcollection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having difficulty pulling the subcollection when I have queried the document using a `.where()`. I keep getting the error:

`TypeError: collectionData.where(...).collection is not a function`

If I use a standard `.doc()` it works, the `.where()` does not work.

`hotels` is a subcollection of each doc in the main collection. The `hotelCollection` is suppose to pass the extracted data through the class to be parsed and executed.

**index.js**

```
exports.hotels = functions.https.onRequest((req,res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {
        const countryCode = req.url.replace('/', '').toUpperCase();
        const hotelCollection = collectionData.where('countryCode', '==', 'VN').collection('hotels');

        switch (req.method) {
            case 'GET':
                Hotels.list(hotelCollection, req, res);
                break;
            case 'POST':
                Hotels.create(hotelCollection, req, res);
                break;
            default:
                res.status(405).send({error: 'An error occurred!'});
                break;
        }
    })
});
```

**hotel.js**

```
let admin = require('firebase-admin');

class Hotels {

    static list(hotelCollection, req, res) {
        let hotelData = [];

        return hotelCollection.collection('hotels').get()
            .then(hotels => {
                hotels.forEach(hotel => {
                    hotelData.push(hotel.data());
                });
                return hotelData;
            })
            .then(hotelData => {
                return res.status(200).send(hotelData);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                return res.status(404).send('Error finding hotel for this country: ' + err);
            });
    }

    static create(hotelCollection, req, res) {
        return hotelCollection.add(req.body)
            .then(result => {
                return res.status(200).send('Hotel has been added!');
            })
            .catch(err => {
                return res.status(404).send('Error adding hotel for this country: ' + err);
            });
    }
}
module.exports = Hotels;
```

**Database**
[image]

Comment: The error message is telling you that `where()` doesn't return an object that has a method called `collection()`.  It returns a Query object that hasn't been executed yet.  It's not clear to me what you expect this code to actually do, given that we can't see the data in the database, we can't see the implementation of the functions on `Hotel`, and we don't know what should be the response it should generate.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have updated the question with more context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Hotels` class, in the `create` method, `hotelCollection` shall be a [`CollectionReference`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html), since you call the `add()` method.

On the other hand, in the `list` method, since you do `hotelCollection.collection('hotels').get()`, it means that `hotelCollection` shall be a [`DocumentReference`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html) (or `hotelCollection` is equal to `admin.firestore()`, which does not seem to be the case...).

So, if you want to have the same signature for these two methods, you should pass the `CollectionReference` corresponding to the `hotels` sub-collection of the document returned by your query.

---

So, first, adapt the `Hotels` class as follows:

```
class Hotels {

    static list(hotelCollection, req, res) {
        let hotelData = [];

        return hotelCollection.get()  // <-- !!! See change here
            .then(hotels => {
                hotels.forEach(hotel => {
                    hotelData.push(hotel.data());
                });
                return res.status(200).send(hotelData);  // !!! <-- and also here, we removed a then()
            })
            .catch(err => {
                return res.status(404).send('Error finding hotel for this country: ' + err);
            });
    }

    static create(hotelCollection, req, res) {
        return hotelCollection.add(req.body)
            .then(result => {
                return res.status(200).send('Hotel has been added!');
            })
            .catch(err => {
                return res.status(404).send('Error adding hotel for this country: ' + err);
            });
    }
}
```

---

Then, call it as follows:

```
exports.hotels = functions.https.onRequest((req,res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {

        const countryCode = req.url.replace('/', '').toUpperCase();

        const countryQuery = collectionData.where('countryCode', '==', 'VN');

        countryQuery.get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
           const countryDocRef = querySnapshot.docs[0].ref;
           const hotelCollection = countryDocRef.collection('hotels');

           switch (req.method) {
              case 'GET':
                  Hotels.list(hotelCollection, req, res);
                  break;
              case 'POST':
                  Hotels.create(hotelCollection, req, res);
                  break;
              default:
                  res.status(405).send({error: 'An error occurred!'});
                  break;
           }

        });

    });
});
```

You first execute the query, then get the first `QueryDocumentSnapshot` of the [`QuerySnapshot`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/QuerySnapshot.html) through the `docs` property, then get its `DocumentReference`, and finally get the document's `hotels` sub-collection, in order to pass it to the `Hotels` methods.

Note that above code is based on two assumptions:

- There is only one document with a given `countryCode` value, hence the use of `docs[0]`;
- The `collectionData` variable holds the collection shown on the "Database" screenshot, i.e. the one on the left part of the screenshot.

---

Finally, note that if you want to get the value of the `countryCode` from the URL of the GET HTTPS Request (i.e. replace the hardcoded `VN` value by a variable value passed through the GET query string parameters), you should use `req.query`, see https://flaviocopes.com/express-get-query-variables/